Why is the box-shadow not showing in my Angular component?
The point is that my header should have a box-shadow But this is not displayed, even though it was defined in the header component box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) If you reduce the height of the header, you will see the box shadow. The header should be 70px high including box-shadow What am I doing wrong?
Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rhsyz2?file=src%2Fmain.ts
Most relevant Code:
/* styles.scss */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

<!-- app.component.html -->
<div class="grid-box">
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <app-header class="header"></app-header>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

/* app.component.scss */
.grid-box {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "nav header" "nav content";
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
    grid-template-rows: 70px auto;
}

.nav {
    grid-area: nav;
    background-color: blue;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #777;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    background-color: red;
}

<!-- header.component.html -->
<div>header</div>

/* header.component.scss */
div {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


We can add the box shadow to the host component and use z-index to ensure the shadow is above the other elements!
:host {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index:2;
}

Stackblitz
If you do not want to change the CSS, you can just keep the last element as the header, so that it will be displayed above all the other elements!
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HeaderComponent } from './app/header/header.component';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HeaderComponent],
  template: `
    <div class="grid-box">
      <div class="nav"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <app-header class="header"></app-header>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Why does it work with z-index:2 ? As far as I know, this only works with absolutely positioned elements and I have never used poition: absolute anywhere.

@coder Think of the elements as paper stacked differently on top of another, when one element is stacked on other, the previous element overlapping parts gets hidden, here box shadow lies outside the element. so its hidden by the other elements, so z-index, is a way to tell the browser, "Hey, stack the elements, based on the order z-index!", z-index applies for all positioning I guess!

In main.ts, change this line:
<app-header class="header"></app-header>

To this:
<app-header style="z-index:1" class="header"></app-header>

In HTML, if there are two elements overlapping and one element is not the child of the other, the later element gets priority. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one. The default z-index is 0.
